# "unable to connect to the remote server" WCF error

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-mobile, synchronization

HI I am doing one wcf sync application just by following

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488004(v=vs.90).aspx

this walk through, but it giving me a web exception saying unable to connect to remote server
[image]

can anyone please help to figure where i am going wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These types of errors are usually two things:

- Make sure whatever you're connecting to is actually accepting connections (you can test services in your browser)
- Make sure that your client and server bindings and endpoints configurations are correct

Comment: I tried the url in browser and it is working my configs are like